# UDT Stack in VBA

Tags: vba, recursion, optimization, collections, stack

### Goal

In transforming a recursive solution to an iterative one, I am trying to create a stack of UDTs(state) as seen below.

### What I've tried & the Issues

The collection implementation of a stack does not work due to UDTs not being allowed in collections.

Implementing the UDTs as classes does not work due to the ~10x performance time (improving the performance is the sole goal of implementing in an iterative solution via a stack).

I have not been able to find a native stack object in VBA.

### Question

Is there a less computationally expensive way to add UDTs to a stack than implementing them as classes?

### FYI

The solution is O(n!((n-1)/2)!) and my goal is solving for n=12 on personal PCs in < 30min

### Code Overview

```
Public Type state
 items() As item2
 path As String
End Type

Public Type item2
 b As Integer
 g As Integer
 n As String
End Type

Sub fuse3(initialState As state)
  Dim stack As collection
  Dim top As state
  Dim bestResult As result2
  stack.Add initialState
  While stack.Count > 0
    top = stack.item(stack.Count) '{ This is a pop
    stack.Remove (stack.Count)        '{
    ...
    ...
  Wend
End Sub
```

### Full Code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Dim paths_explored As Double

Public Type state
     items() As item2
     path As String
End Type
Public Type item2
     b As Integer
     g As Integer
     n As String
End Type

Public Type result2
     v As Integer
     p As String
End Type



'Recursive
Sub Fuser3()


Dim secs1, secs2 As Single
secs1 = Timer()
Dim markedABase As Boolean
    markedABase = True
    'note, if gem value is 1337 this means it was marked as the base and should not be fused onto others
    ' and also means that 1337 should be subtracted from the final answer

    '


    'input data
    Dim item1 As item2
    item1.b = 100
    item1.g = 1337
    item1.n = "1"

    Dim item2 As item2
    item2.b = 100
    item2.g = 64
    item2.n = "2"

    Dim item3 As item2
    item3.b = 120
    item3.g = 64
    item3.n = "3"

    Dim item4 As item2
    item4.b = 120
    item4.g = 64
    item4.n = "4"

    Dim item5 As item2
    item5.b = 100
    item5.g = 64
    item5.n = "5"

    Dim item6 As item2
    item6.b = 260
    item6.g = 24
    item6.n = "6"

    Dim item7 As item2
    item7.b = 191
    item7.g = 30
    item7.n = "7"

    Dim item8 As item2
    item8.b = 197
    item8.g = 30
    item8.n = "8"

    Dim item9 As item2
    item9.b = 187
    item9.g = 30
    item9.n = "9"

    Dim inputItems(7) As item2
    inputItems(1) = item1
    inputItems(2) = item2
    inputItems(3) = item3
    inputItems(4) = item4
    inputItems(5) = item5
    inputItems(6) = item6
    inputItems(7) = item7
    'inputItems(8) = item8
    'inputItems(9) = item9


    Dim inputPath As String
    inputPath = "If you asked Doll, she would would fuse "
    paths_explored = 0

    'function
    Dim initialState As state
    initialState.items = inputItems
    initialState.path = inputPath
    Dim answer As result2
    answer = fuse3(initialState)
    secs2 = Timer()
    If markedABase Then
        MsgBox (answer.v - 1337 & " in " & paths_explored & " loops, " & secs2 - secs1 & " seconds   " & answer.p)
    Else
        MsgBox (answer.v & " in " & paths_explored & " loops, " & secs2 - secs1 & " seconds   " & answer.p)
    End If

End Sub

Function fuse3(initialState As state) As result2

Dim stack As collection
Dim top As state
Dim bestResult As result2
stack.Add initialState
While stack.Count > 0
    top = stack.item(stack.Count) '{ This is a pop
    stack.Remove (stack.Count)        '{

    Dim items() As item2
    items = top.items
    Dim path As String
    path = top.path

    Select Case UBound(items)
      Case 0
        'error
      Case 1
        Dim result As Integer
        result = items(1).b + items(1).g
        If result > bestResult.v Then
            bestResult.v = result
            bestResult.p = path
        End If
      Case Else
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        For i = 1 To UBound(items)
          For j = 1 To UBound(items)
            If i = j Then
            Else
                If items(j).b + items(j).g < items(i).b Or items(j).g = 1337 Then
                Else
                  Dim fPath As String
                  fPath = path + items(j).n + "-->" + items(i).n + ", "
                  ReDim newItems(UBound(items) - 1) As item2

                  'newItems = items
                  'remove item j by not copying it over
                  For k = 1 To UBound(items)
                    If k = i Then
                        If k < j Then
                            newItems(k).b = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((items(i).b + items(j).b + items(j).g) / 2, 0)
                            newItems(k).g = items(k).g
                            newItems(k).n = items(k).n
                        Else
                            newItems(k - 1).b = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((items(i).b + items(j).b + items(j).g) / 2, 0)
                            newItems(k - 1).g = items(k).g
                            newItems(k - 1).n = items(k).n
                        End If
                    Else
                        If k < j Then
                            newItems(k).b = items(k).b
                            newItems(k).g = items(k).g
                            newItems(k).n = items(k).n
                        ElseIf k > j Then
                            newItems(k - 1).b = items(k).b
                            newItems(k - 1).g = items(k).g
                            newItems(k - 1).n = items(k).n
                        End If
                    End If
                  Next

                  Dim newState As state
                  newState.items = newItems
                  newState.path = fPath
                  stack.Add newState

                End If
            End If
          Next
        Next

    End Select
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a working recursive solution?

Comment: Yes, do you think it is relevant/should be added to the post?

Comment: I think you should post it on CodeReview.

Comment: How be are the concatenated strings getting?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a .Net Stack wrapper class that I wrote:

### Stack Class

```
Public Control As Object

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Me.Control = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
End Sub

Rem Clear() Removes all objects from the Stack.
Public Sub Clear(value As Variant)
    Me.Control.Clear
End Sub

Rem Creates a shallow copy of the Control.
Public Function Clone()
    Set Clone = Control.Clone
End Function

Rem Contains(Object)    Determines whether an element is in the Stack.
Public Function Contains(value As Variant) As Boolean
    Contains = Me.Control.Contains(value)
End Function

Rem Gets the number of elements contained in the Stack.
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = Me.Control.Count
End Function

Rem Determines whether the specified ObjectA is the Control
Public Function Equals(Control As Object) As Boolean
    Equals = Control.Equals(Control)
End Function

Rem GetHashCode()
Rem Serves as the default hash function. (Inherited from Object.)
Public Function GetHashCode() As Long
    GetHashCode = Control.GetHashCode
End Function

Rem Removes and returns the object at the top of the Stack.
Public Function Pop()
    If IsObject(Me.Control.Peek) Then
        Set Pop = Me.Control.Pop
    Else
        Pop = Me.Control.Peek
    End If
End Function

Rem Inserts an object at the top of the Stack.
Public Sub Push(value As Variant)
    Me.Control.Push value
End Sub

Rem Custom Function
Function This() As TTools.stack
    Set This = Me
End Function

Rem Copies the Stack to a new array.
Public Function ToArray() As Variant
    ToArray = Me.Control.ToArray()
End Function

Rem Returns a string that represents the current object.(Inherited from Object.)
Public Function toString() As String
    toString = Control.toString
End Function
```

---

`Math.Round()` is 20 times faster then using `Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp()`.

> ```
> newItems(k - 1).b = Math.Round((items(i).b + items(j).b + items(j).g) / 2, 0)
> ```